# First time flying with carry-on only. Can I carry double edged razor blades with me?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

Blades are in their original pack. All toiletries are in a separate small bag. That's inside my luggage

Is this ok? I live nomadically so it's not like I have a home I can leave it behind and I don't want to deal with buying a new blade every time I need to shave. So I'll just keep carrying this with me. If they take it, oh well. If they take it again, oh well, again. ... Good idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bring a pack of razor blades on a plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98311/can-i-bring-a-pack-of-razor-blades-on-a-plane)

Comment: Safety razors blades can be purchased in many convenience or department stores like CVS, Walgreens, Target, Walmart, etc and they are usually very cheap (<$5). It would probably be easier for you to avoid the hassle and just buy them at the destination.

Comment: I get around this when I travel by simply not shaving while I'm abroad

Comment: I travel the globe perpetually with Gillette 5 bladers all the time in checked and at times in onboard luggage... Never questioned once!

Answer (score 19):

Attempt at a more generic answer:

1. You can always check online at https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all In this example just put in "razor" in the search box and it will tell you exactly what the rules are. In this case "blades" are NOT allowed
2. While this website only covers US rules, I have never seen any significant discrepancy between US and other countries, so this is good starting point for international travel as well
3. Be prepared for inconsistencies. I've had security officers remove items that were clearly allowed. I also got through with items that were clearly not allowed. Just go with flow and don't argue (it won't help). Just let them toss the item and buy a new one (unless it's something valuable).
4. Every check point has somewhat different rules: what has to come out of bag, liquids, shoes, belt, jackets, etc. Just look around and see what other people are doing and who gets yelled at.
5. If you travel with somewhat unusual items, you can choose to take them out proactively. In my case this has been Rubik's Cubes (no idea why) and a measurement microphone (which is a longish metal object).
6. Be prepared for inconsistencies: I have been yelled for not taking stuff out and I have been yelled at for taking stuff out. Just ignore it.
7. Occasionally you may find the label "SSSS" on your boarding pass. Congratulations: you have won the lottery for "Secondary Security Screening Selection", i.e. you will be pulled out for a separate manual screening. Head to security a bit earlier and make sure you carry-on is squeaky clean.

Comment: The point **Just Don't Argue** is an incredibly important point!

Comment: If their action is clearly against the regulations, what's the harm in asking for a supervisor who can double-check the decision? Sure, I'd lose some time, but I'd hate to throw away something that can still be used.

Comment: @helm The harm is that even if you're doing things by the book, the TSA has wide latitude to make your travel experience unpleasant

Comment: @BThompson It can still save you from losing an item that may be quite expensive (sometimes more than the the ticket). Sometimes the other option is just to go home and don't fly. Arguing may be worth it if it has the potential to save the trip.

Comment: @helm: the harm is that they can make you miss your flight. They can drag this out as long as they want. It's the biggest lever that they have and they know it.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава fortunately, when you do the actual cost/benefit analysis, you know how expensive the item is.  If they're going to trash your $5 explicitly-allowed disposable razor, it is probably better not to ask for a supervisor.  If the item really _is_ worth hundreds of dollars, by all means, persist.

Comment: There are many discrepancies between TSA policies and other countries. Liquids is the one that comes to mind; many countries have no restrictions on liquids in hand luggage at all. Some countries have different security policies for domestic flights vs international flights. I’d also say that outside of the US it’s ok to question when the security staff get stuff wrong or calmly to ask to discuss with a supervisor: and I have seen subordinates overruled. Not everywhere is TSA where people want to be nasty; some countries have security people who are actually trying to do a good job.

Answer (score 9):

[TSA explicitly prohibits it](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2018/08/07/top-five-items-people-ask-about-razors-batteries-makeup-shampoo-deodorant#:%7E:text=Safety%20Razors%3A%20Because%20the%20razor,same%20applies%20for%20straight%20razors.). If you want, you have to use a disposable razor in which blades cannot be removed easily.

Comment: TSA prohibits safety razors and straight razors, however, disposable razors are "permissible in carry-on luggage with the blade and replacement cartridges." Electric shavers are fine, too.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that "disposable razors" includes those high quality types with a [non-disposable handle and (relatively expensive) disposable blade cartridges](https://i.imgur.com/Zxz1Ojc.png), not just the crappy all-in-one disposable type.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that is very worth pointing out. Thanks! In my vernacular, “disposable razor” is only the plastic all in one kind that you (at least used to) be able to get like 5 for a dollar and you can get for free at say mid level and up hotels in the US. Good to know TSA includes allows the other kind.